# Change Option Strict setting

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a large VB.NET application were 'Option Strict' is set to off (set by the previous developer).  I am thinking about setting it to on.  Is it advisable to do this? I am trying to determine whether I should:

1. Leave it as it is.  Any new VB.NET apps will have option strict set to true
2. Change it

I cannot find any guidance on this from MSDN.  I read that Option Strict was there to help VB6 developers in their transition to VB.NET.

I understand that there will be a lot of changes needed.  I am trying to decide if it is worth it.

Comment: Try setting it to on and see what breaks when you debug the the application.

Comment: you just may need add a lot of `.ToString()` and casting/converting.

Comment: To me, it's worth it if it can be done in 2 days or so... otherwise wait til you have that kind of time

Comment: it does more than help VB6 people; it warns of all sorts of invalid assignments; late binding, incomplete declarations (`Dim x`) etc.  There is no Option Strict Off in C# which is telling.

Comment: Open Explicit is required IMO. You can also make some settings in Project, Properties, Compile, Warnings that will help tighten up your code. You can turn some of the show stopper Strict errors into warnings.

Comment: @rheitzman, thanks for mentioning warnings. I like that idea. Then i can gradually improve the quality of the code over time. Do you agree? Please post an answer for credit.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new `Option Infer` setting that makes it sometimes okay to have Option Strict off (because Option Infer supersedes Option Strict such that it has no effect).

You may find this MSDN article helpful:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx

Absent Option Infer, in most situations I strongly prefer and advise using Option Strict. However, you need to be careful just turning it on. Even if you fix any new compiler errors that come up, changing an existing project from Option Strict Off to Option Strict On can result *runtime* exceptions, where the old code relied on an implicit runtime conversion that is no longer permitted.

Therefore, I would probably not wholesale change your existing project. I might change one class/module/file at a time, over a long period of time, as I had to maintain those modules anyway. What I would do right away is start working on my unit tests. I feel like unit testing and static type checking have some significant overlap in the kinds of errors they prevent. Unit testing is useful to everyone, but it's of special importance if you're not getting the benefit of type checking from your compiler.

This brings up my broader philosophy about unit testing: you *should* be doing unit testing, no matter who you are, for at least regression testing (as you fix a bug, write a test for the bug to keep it from recurring in later edits). If you're using a dynamic language, and VB with Option Strict Off counts for this, you should also be doing the full Test Driven Development philosophy, where you write tests before you write code, and you push for 100% code coverage. Conversely, languages with static type checking allow the compiler to weed out many of the errors that Test Driven Development is used to prevent, and so you get by will less tedious test writing (not that you shouldn't do testing at all, but that 100% code coverage is likely not necessary, nor is the test-first philosophy).

Comment: Option Strict and Option Infer can co-exist.

Comment: @Neolisk Yes, I misread the chart in my link at first: it matters if a variable is declared with no type and no assignment. If the variable is assigned to, Infer replaces it.

Comment: I would like to see an example where Option Strict On results in a runtime instead of a compile time failure.